# Google Actions is it possible to use CameraStream with Dialogflow fulfillment?

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am trying to integrate the IP camera with my google actions.
I have developed several commands such as change camera name, start rotation, start recording etc., and implementing it with my Google fulfillment using [Actions on Google Client Library for Node.js v2](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview).  After I read the guide, I found that [CameraStream](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/camerastream) is available in Smart Home SDK, but I do not see any reference for Dialogflow with my own hosting fulfillment server.

Is there anyway to use Dialogflow with Smart Home CameraStream Trait? or do I have to switch to Google Smart Home SDK? Because I also want to train my own phase. How should I do it if it is only available for Home SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a direct smart home integration for the Google Assistant, you should use the [smart home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) integration. This will allow you to give commands directly like "show me the doorbell" to get the camera stream.

If you are looking for additional options that are not available as smart home traits at the moment, such as "start rotation", you should look into Dialogflow as a conversational action.

The important thing to keep in mind is that smart home actions do not require natural language processing. If the user says "show me the doorbell", your server does not get the user's query nor needs to interpret it. Your server will only get an execute command for that device. Dialogflow is a great tool for natural language processing, but is not used for smart home actions.

Comment: is it possible to use both of them inside one app? Like having both smart home and Dialogflow action in one google assistant app? Because when I create project on Actions on Google console, I am only able to choose one of them

Comment: No. You would either use Dialogflow / custom NLP, or smart home / provided NLP